# vba object required while convert the value to date

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to convert the value to the date by using the VBA, when executed the code, it showed the message

> Object Required

I want the result is:
[image]

The code as follows:

```
Dim wb2 As Workbook
Dim wsw As Worksheet
Dim destsheetName As String
destsheetName = "Worksheet"
Set wb2 = ThisWorkbook
Set wsw = wb2.Sheets(destsheetName)
ConvertToDate2


Sub ConvertToDate2()
Dim lastrowB As Integer
lastrowB = wsw.Cells(wsw.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
For i = 5380 To lastrowB
If wsw.Cells(i, 2).Value <> "" Then
wsw.Cells(i, 2).Value.NumberFormat = "dd-mm-yyyy"
End If
End Sub
```

I cannot figure out what the problem, would you please provide any suggestion? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is:

```
wsw.Cells(i, 2).Value.NumberFormat = "dd-mm-yyyy"
```

The value doesn't have a Numberformat. The `Numberformat` is a property of the cell (which is a `Range`, and a range has a `.Numberformat`)

So it should have been:

```
wsw.Cells(i, 2).NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
```

Comment: Use "dd/mm/yyyy" for the NumberFormat if the ouput in the picture is what they actually want